# FireFox 34 setMinutes BUG?

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, time

There is a strange behaviour of the FireFox 34 setMinutes date method to set the 60 minutes for 2008 year 01 January 23 hour 00 minutes 00 sec. It is expected that will increase day but this does not.

```
var initDate = [2008, 0, 1];
var d = new Date(initDate[0], initDate[1], initDate[2]);
document.body.innerHTML += d + "<br/>";
d.setHours(23);
d.setMinutes(60);
document.body.innerHTML += d + "<br/>";
```

The FireFox 34 result is:

```
Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time) 
Tue Jan 01 2008 23:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
```

instead of Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m:

```
Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
Wed Jan 02 2008 01:00:00 GMT+0400 (Russia TZ 2 Daylight Time)
```

If I change the year to 2006 the result is ok:

```
Sun Jan 01 2006 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
Mon Jan 02 2006 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dp8xvf8/1/

Is it a bug?

**UPDATE:** IE 8 and 9 has the same behaviour, but 10-11 is ok.

Comment: There's the obvious point that Chrome has changed timezone but FireFox hasn't; I assume you're in that location yourself, was there any significant change at that time? I've not been able to find anything online around that date.

Comment: What behavior do you see if you `setMinutes` less than `60`? (e.g., what does `d.setMinutes(58);` produce?) I don't think I can test your script without changing my browser's timezone/location.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I'm in that location but before last FireFox updates the problem has not been appearing.

Comment: @apsillers The result: "Sun Jan 01 2006 23:58:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)"

Comment: @apsillers "Tue Jan 01 2008 23:58:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)"

Comment: setMinutes is supposed to take as first parameter an int value between 0 and 59.

Comment: @Hacketo You are right. Expected values are 0-59, but other values are allowed: -1 will result in the last minute of the previous hour, 60 will result in the first minute of the next hour.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setminutes.asp

Comment: can not see this on https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/setMinutes , it's just saying that it will try to update the date if a value is out of range (ex with 100 sec in the doc), but not saying what w3school said.

Comment: @Hacketo Look at this: If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMinutes() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the minutes will be incremented by 1 (minutesValue + 1), and 40 will be used for seconds.

Comment: @Hacketo, the [ES 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.11) agrees with El Gans, as does the [6.0 draft](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-maketime). This may indeed be a bug in Firefox 34.

Comment: Same weird bug on my firefox 41... It's been creating an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0):

Given the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), I believe that this is indeed intended behavior. In particular, notice that the [MakeTime function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.11) contains no overflow checks (i.e., it does not determine whether the number of minutes is less than 60). The MakeDate function behaves similarly; hence, Firefox is actually following the specification correctly.

Comment: No, the spec calculates the number-of-milliseconds-since-day-0 by essentially adding up the individual components. Thus setting minutes to 60 should change the hour.

Answer (score 0):

This works as intended for me in Firefox 39.0.3 as well as the current development build (42a), as I get:

```
"Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
"Wed Jan 02 2008 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
```

This is also what the ES specification requires.

If this still does not work for you (which would be surprising), and especially if you see timezone-related weirdness, you should also mention your system TZ settings.